# RotateX stops with overflow hidden

Tags: css, css-animations, css-transforms

I have a simple animation using keyframes and transforms, specifically `rotateX` and `rotateZ`. The animation works as I expect (at least in Chrome, haven't tried others yet).

Now that I have that working, I want to hide the animated elements if they exceed their parent. I put the normal `overflow: hidden;` on the parent.

Then the `rotateX` simply stops being rendered. The `rotateZ` continues on expected. Oddly, it looks as though the element continues to transform when inspected, but the child elements only respect the `rotateZ`.

```css
@keyframes stir {
  0% {
    transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateZ(-25deg);
  }
  25% {
    transform: rotateX(3deg) rotateZ(0deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateZ(25deg);
  }
  75% {
    transform: rotateX(-3deg) rotateZ(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateZ(-25deg);
  }
}
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.mixing {
  position: relative;
  width: 80px;
  padding-top: 50px;
  margin: 50px auto;
}
.mixing .rim,
.mixing .rimb {
  width: 80px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  border-radius: 40px / 10px;
  background: #fff;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 5;
}
.mixing .rimb {
  z-index: 3;
}
.mixing .sides {
  position: relative;
  background: #fff;
  height: 8px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: -18px 0 0;
  border-left: 2px solid #000;
  border-right: 2px solid #000;
  top: 10px;
  z-index: 4;
}
.mixing .bowl {
  width: 70px;
  height: 40px;
  margin: -16px auto 0;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 0 0 30px 30px / 0 0 40px 40px;
}
.mixing .spoon-box {
  width: 120px;
  height: 70px;
  border-radius: 0 0 60px 60px / 0 0 20px 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -2px;
  left: -20px;
  z-index: 10;
  perspective: 25px;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
.mixing .spoon {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -9px;
  bottom: -50px;
  transform-origin: center bottom;
  animation: stir 2s infinite;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
}
.mixing .spoon .stick {
  height: 55px;
  width: 8px;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  border-radius: 3px 3px 0 0;
  border-width: 2px 2px 0px;
  background: #fff;
  margin: 8px 5px -4px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}
.mixing .spoon .cup {
  position: relative;
  height: 22px;
  width: 18px;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 9px / 11px;
}
.broken .spoon-box {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="mixing">
  <div class="rim"></div>
  <div class="sides"></div>
  <div class="rimb"></div>
  <div class="bowl"></div>
  <div class="spoon-box">
    <div class="spoon">
      <div class="stick"></div>
      <div class="cup"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="mixing broken">
  <div class="rim"></div>
  <div class="sides"></div>
  <div class="rimb"></div>
  <div class="bowl"></div>
  <div class="spoon-box">
    <div class="spoon">
      <div class="stick"></div>
      <div class="cup"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/freer4/pen/jJNEpP

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using [clip-path](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path) css rule instead of the `overflow: hidden`? After brief testing on latest Firefox and Chrome it appears that your issue with `rotateZ` not being applied is fixed. As a nice bonus, you can be more specific with clipping, so to match the bowl shape you can use `clip-path: ellipse(...)`, like in the picture below:

[image: bowl clipping]

However, be advised, that `clip-path` is not supported on [IE and Edge](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-clip-path).

The modified example can be found in this [forked codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JzrGbm) or in the snippet below:

```css
@keyframes stir {
  0% {
    transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateZ(-25deg);
  }
  25% {
    transform: rotateX(3deg) rotateZ(0deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateZ(25deg);
  }
  75% {
    transform: rotateX(-3deg) rotateZ(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateZ(-25deg);
  }
}
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.mixing {
  position: relative;
  width: 80px;
  padding-top: 50px;
  margin: 50px auto;
}
.mixing .rim,
.mixing .rimb {
  width: 80px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  border-radius: 40px / 10px;
  background: #fff;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 5;
}
.mixing .rimb {
  z-index: 3;
}
.mixing .sides {
  position: relative;
  background: #fff;
  height: 8px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: -18px 0 0;
  border-left: 2px solid #000;
  border-right: 2px solid #000;
  top: 10px;
  z-index: 4;
}
.mixing .bowl {
  width: 70px;
  height: 40px;
  margin: -16px auto 0;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 0 0 30px 30px / 0 0 40px 40px;
}
.mixing .spoon-box {
  width: 120px;
  height: 70px;
  border-radius: 0 0 60px 60px / 0 0 20px 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -2px;
  left: -20px;
  z-index: 10;
  perspective: 25px;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
.mixing .spoon {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -9px;
  bottom: -50px;
  transform-origin: center bottom;
  animation: stir 2s infinite;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
}
.mixing .spoon .stick {
  height: 55px;
  width: 8px;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  border-radius: 3px 3px 0 0;
  border-width: 2px 2px 0px;
  background: #fff;
  margin: 8px 5px -4px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}
.mixing .spoon .cup {
  position: relative;
  height: 22px;
  width: 18px;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 9px / 11px;
}
.broken .spoon-box {
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  clip-path: ellipse(80px 49px at 60px 22px);
}
```

```html
<div class="mixing">
  <div class="rim"></div>
  <div class="sides"></div>
  <div class="rimb"></div>
  <div class="bowl"></div>
  <div class="spoon-box">
    <div class="spoon">
      <div class="stick"></div>
      <div class="cup"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="mixing broken">
  <div class="rim"></div>
  <div class="sides"></div>
  <div class="rimb"></div>
  <div class="bowl"></div>
  <div class="spoon-box">
    <div class="spoon">
      <div class="stick"></div>
      <div class="cup"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```